# Crystal Report viewer always keeps asking me to login

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have this problem: Crystal Report viewer always keeps asking me to login but i don't know how to change the server name and database so that I can Login. This is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class print : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = config.getConnection();

        ReportDocument crypt = new ReportDocument();

        public print()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void print_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PersonalInformation", con);

            DataSet dst = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(dst, "employeesinformation");

            crypt.Load(@"C:\Users\ASPIRE\Documents\mao ni\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\CrystalReport1.rpt");
            crypt.SetDataSource(dst);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crypt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your connection string ?

Comment: You are opening the connection, there must be some database username and password, if that is not provided in code, it will ask for it. Try adding it in code.